# Passing input values to controller without showing in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" >
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" id="inputpassword" name="inputpassword" placeholder="@ViewBag.PlaceHolder1st">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" id="inputPasswordconfirm" name="inputPasswordconfirm" placeholder="@ViewBag.PlaceHolder1st">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-info" data-loading-text=@ViewBag.ButtonLoading>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>
                            @ViewBag.Button
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("reset_password/{userid}/{language}")]
public ActionResult PasswordReset(string userid, string language, string pass, string inputpassword, string inputPasswordcomfirm)
{
        // Do stuff
        return View();
}
```

When i press the button, get the values of inputs object... fine.. but, two things:

1. Finally my url shows the password values

   localhost:61443/reset_password/D1171DAC3EA22AAF2FB133B30FA32AAD23B73E7232A56BFC/en?inputpassword=1234&inputPasswordconfirm=1234

   How to hide my password values from url or change the way that i get the values for dont show my passwords in the url ? (without sessions)
2. How to change the button click event to redirect to other method in the same controller ? (Considering that i use the "Route" attribute). I tried adding the action property to Form tag, changing the "method" property to Form tag, but didn't work even still entering the "PasswordReset" method.

Comment: You need to do a POST, not a GET.

Comment: @JamieD77 why @ Html.BeginForm and not <Form/> tag ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i tried with other method in the controller class, but never enters the method... well ..I could not do it the right way maybe

Comment: because it's a helper.. and it helps.. you get some intellisense that might help you solve some of the questions you're asking

Comment: @Makito, Show what you tried. You need a `<form>` element with `method="post"` and a separate controller method marked with `[HttpPost]` And you really should start learning to use the HtmlHelpers to generate your html.

Comment: @StephenMuecke haaa ok, yeah i come from HTML, im newbie with asp.net,  that's why i use the HTML tag Form. when i tried method post, I created the method on the same controller.. I'll try creating a new controller.

Comment: You do not need a different controller. Both the `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` methods should be in the same controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Post method cannot be used for sharing your website links.

Comment: @QMaster, Of course not - OP does not want to share the password values

Comment: @StephenMuecke That is obvious :) I mean that in a global vision according to the publicity of question title.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the form method to POST instead of GET, then the responses will not be in the URL, but instead be passed via the HTTP_REQUEST variable to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should undestand the difference between `HTTP` methods `POST` and `GET`

[This is the most simplistic explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

If you want to `POST` some data to a web server you should use `POST`.

Comment: yeah, i understand the methods POST and GET, but, i tried created other method in controller, using post attribute and the method property in Form tag, but doesn't  enters the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

**View**

```
@model ResetPasswordViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset password";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Inputpassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Inputpassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InputPasswordcomfirm, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.InputPasswordcomfirm, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Language, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Language, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Model**

```
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string Pass { get; set; }
        public string Inputpassword { get; set; }
        public string InputPasswordcomfirm { get; set; }
    }
```

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    // Do stuff
    return View();
}
```